# How can I convert uploaded file on-the-fly and stream it directly to amazon S3 within sails

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js, formidable

I am working on an application that is sending a audio file to a server powered by sails.js.

I need to convert this audio file on-the-fly and send the converted data to amazon S3 using node streams.

I don't want to store data on the server but directly stream the upload file to S3 after it has been converted.

Do you know a way to do that?

I tried using formidable, but I couldn't get it working. Did anyone succeed implementing such a thing?

Thanks

**EDIT**

As jibsales noticed, it will probably be better if I show you a piece of what I've tried so far. So basically my strategy is to use formidable, fluent-ffmpeg and knox with streams.

I plan to receive the file stream with formidable and write chunks of received data in a first stream (stream 1) that will be the entry point for the conversion with fluent-ffmpeg. Then fluent-ffmpeg writes the output stream into stream2 which is the entry point of Knox.

The first problem I have to face, is the fact that formidable doesn't seem to work. However I'm not sure my strategy is good...

The code so far looks like this:

```
upload : function(req,res){

  //to streams to transfer file data
  var stream1 = new stream.Stream(); //stream for the incoming file data
  var stream2 = new stream.Stream(); //stream for the converted file data

  var client = knox.createClient({
            key: 'APIKEY'
          , secret: 'SECRET'
          , bucket: 'bucket'
        });

  //Using formidable to acces data chunks
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){ //form.parse is not called
  if(err){
      return res.json(err);
  }else{
      return res.send('ok');       
  }
  });

  //overriding form.onPart to get the file data chunk
  form.onPart = function(part) { 
        sails.log('getting part...');

        if (!part.filename) {
            form.handlePart(part);
            return;
        }
        //we put the data chunk in stream1 to convert it
        part.on('data', function(chunk) {
            stream1.write(chunk[1]);
        });
  }

  form.on('error',function(err){
    return sails.log(err);
  });

  form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    sails.log(bytesReceived);
  });

  //conversion process
  var proc = new ffmpeg({ source : stream1})
  .withAudioCodec('libfdk_aac')
  .toFormat('mp3')
  .writeToStream(stream2, {end:true}, function(retcode, error){ 
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });


client.putStream(stream2, '/file.mp3', headers, function(err, response){
  return res.send(response);
});

},
```

Comment: You should post code showing what you have tried instead of asking us to come up with an answer for you – this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I'm not asking for code writing but for a clue on how to do it... Sorry if you think I expect a fully implemented answer. I'll update my question with my attempts to give you more insight if it can help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a way to convert files on-the-fly with fluent-ffmpeg and formidable. However it seems impossible for the moment to stream the converted chunks comming out of ffmpeg conversion directly to amazon as you must precise the "Content-Length" header which is unknown during the conversion...

For the first part (client upload) I first had to disable express bodyParser on the upload route in a config/express.js file :

```
var express = require('sails/node_modules/express');

module.exports.express = {
   bodyParser: function() {
    return function (req, res, next){
        console.log(req.path);
        if (!(req.path === '/upload' && req.method === 'POST')) {
        return express.bodyParser()(req, res, next);
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    }
   }
}
```

For the implementation I used a transform stream that does basically nothing. It just get the right parts of the uploaded data (the ones related to file data). It links formidable parser to fluent-ffmpeg. Then I can only save the converted file on the disk before sending it to amazon...

```
upload : function(req,res){

  var Transform =  Stream.Transform; //stream for the incoming file data
  var client = knox.createClient({
            key: 'KEY'
          , secret: 'SECRET'
          , bucket: 'BUCKET',
          region : 'eu-west-1' //don't forget the region (My bucket is in Europe)
        });


  function InputStream(options) 
  {
          if(!(this instanceof InputStream))
          {
            return  new InputStream(options);
          }
          Transform.call(this,options);
          return;
  };

  util.inherits(InputStream, Transform);

  var inputDataStream = new InputStream;

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
  { 
    if(err){
        return res.send(err);
    }else{
        return;     
    }
  });

    form.onPart = function(part) 
    { 
        if (!part.filename) 
        {
            form.handlePart(part);
            return;
        }
        //we put the data chunk in stream1 to convert it
        part.on('data', function (chunk) 
        {
           if(!inputDataStream.write(chunk));
            form.pause()
            inputDataStream.once('drain', function(){form.resume()});
        });

        part.on('end', function (chunk){
          inputDataStream.end(chunk);
        });

    }

  InputStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, enc, cb)
  {
    this.push(chunk);
    cb();
  }

  var proc = new ffmpeg({ source : inputDataStream})
      .withAudioBitrate('64k')
      .withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
      .toFormat('mp3')
      .saveToFile('file.mp3',  function (retcode, error){ 
        console.log('file has been converted successfully');
        res.send('ok');
          var upload = new MultiPartUpload(
          {
            client : client,
            objectName: 'file.mp3',
            file: 'file.mp3'
          }, function(err,body){
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log(body);
            return;
          });

      });
  },
```

**EDIT**

Using knox-mpu you can actually stream data to amazon s3 directly ! You just have to create another transform stream that will be the source of your upload and knox-mpu do the magic. Thanks you all!

Comment: Try using the Knox MPU module for streaming to S3-I believe if you use Amazon's multi-part upload API, you don't need the content length in advance.

Comment: Yes, I just found that! it's great! I will update the answer soon... The last problem concerns concurrent uploads...

Answer (score 4):

The reason formidable isn't working is that the default Sails body parser is parsing the request before formidable can get to it.  In order to get this to work, you'll have to bypass the Sails body parser for multi-part form uploads.  So, in `config/express.js`:

```
    var express = require('sails/node_modules/express');
    module.exports.express = {
       bodyParser: function(options) {
         return function (req, res, next) {
          if (!req.headers['content-type'] || req.headers['content-type'].indexOf('multipart/form-data') === -1) {
            return express.bodyParser()(req, res, next);
          } else {
            return next();
          }
         }
       }
    }
```

This just skips the body parser entirely if the `content-type` header includes `multipart/form-data`.  Otherwise, it executes the default express body parser.  Note that the default Sails body parser is slightly fancier than what comes with Express (if it can't parse the request, it fakes an `application/json` header and retries), so if you want the extra goodness you'll have to copy/paste the code from the core in to the `bodyParser` function above.  But in most cases you won't miss it ;-)

We're working on a better file parser for Sails that will hopefully take care of some of this for you, but in the mean time this is your best bet!

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried your solution, for the moment I get an error when I lift my app... the req.headers seems to not be defined ... I'm still trying to get it work! Apart from that the solution to my question seems a bit difficult to put in place, I'll try to improve my Question with further information about what I succeeded to implement as soon as I can get formidable working !

Comment: Ok if figured out the problem, bodyParser should be a function taking to arguments and returning a function with arguments req, res, next, it will appear in my coming update of my question. Thank you very much !